# What does "full of juice and vinegar" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), J.J asks his press agent Sidney
about this boy Dallas who is having a affair with his sister:

> Sidney: I've cased this kid. I know his ins and outs. He's **full of
> juice and vinegar**, just waiting...for a big shot like you to put on
> the squeeze.

What does "full of juice and vinegar" mean?

Comment: Used to be 'piss and vinegar' when I was a boy. Full of youthful energy.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The concept has its more contemporary [renderings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3L0gVSpHP0) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Micheal_Harvey has mentioned, the original phrase is "full of piss and vinegar":

> To say that people are “full of piss and vinegar” is to say that they are **brimming with energy**. Although many speakers assume the phrase must have a negative connotation, this expression is more often used as a compliment, “vinegar” being an old slang term for enthusiastic energy [Source](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/30/pith-and-vinegar/)

So the story is telling us that Dallas is super energetic.

Comment: The Google Books Ngram Viewer for 1800-2019 reveals that "piss and vinegar" made its first appearance in 1933, but "juice and vinegar" goes back to 1800. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=juice+and+vinegar%2Cpiss+and+vinegar&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjuice%20and%20vinegar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiss%20and%20vinegar%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjuice%20and%20vinegar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiss%20and%20vinegar%3B%2Cc0